# Callback function after multiple scripts loaded

Tags: javascript

I have two script file like this

```
  <script  onload="mready();" src="moment.js"></script>
  <script  onload="jready();" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Above code calls **mready**() after moment.js is loaded and **jready**() after jquery loaded ,  How do I call another function after both scripts are loaded.

Comment: Just put your own script below the two others; <script>s are loaded and executed in order. There's no need to have a function like `mready()` in the first place.

Comment: No , sometimes when the scripts are big , smaller scripts are getting loaded first.

Comment: No, that is simply not true. The size of a script doesn't matter. Unless the `async` or `defer` attribute is added to the tag, scripts will always load in full then run, in order.

Comment: Here's the reference question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts (this isn't a duplicate though, since you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist)

Answer (score -1):

Just write a function to check if both are ready:

```
let mIsReady = false;
let jIsReady = false;

function mready () {
    mIsReady = true;
    ready();
}

function jready () {
    jIsReady = true;
    ready();
}

function ready () {
    if (mIsReady && jIsReady) {
        // do what you need here
    }
}
```