# Retrieve the values for 'long_name' and 'ID' from the script

Tags: javascript, arrays

```html
    <script>
    INST = {"environment":"production","logPageViews":true,"editorButtons":[{"name":"YouTube","id":6,"favorite":false,"url":"https://www.example.org/lti_public_resources/?tool_id=youtube","icon_url":"https://www.example.org/assets/lti_public_resources/youtube_icon.png","canvas_icon_class":null,"width":560,"height":600,"use_tray":false,"description":"\u003cp\u003eSearch publicly available YouTube videos. A new icon will show up in your course rich editor letting you search YouTube and click to embed videos in your course material.\u003c/p\u003e\n"}]};
    ENV = {"ASSET_HOST":null,"active_brand_config_json_url":"/dist/brandable_css/default/variables-high_contrast-7dd4b80918af0e0218ec0229e4bd5873.json","active_brand_config":null,"confetti_branding_enabled":false,"url_to_what_gets_loaded_inside_the_tinymce_editor_css":["/dist/brandable_css/default/variables-high_contrast-7dd4b80918af0e0218ec0229e4bd5873.css","/dist/brandable_css/new_styles_high_contrast/bundles/what_gets_loaded_inside_the_tinymce_editor-b645f3a457.css","/dist/brandable_css/no_variables/bundles/fonts-8022a0771c.css"],"url_for_high_contrast_tinymce_editor_css":["/dist/brandable_css/default/variables-high_contrast-7dd4b80918af0e0218ec0229e4bd5873.css","/dist/brandable_css/new_styles_high_contrast/bundles/what_gets_loaded_inside_the_tinymce_editor-b645f3a457.css","/dist/brandable_css/no_variables/bundles/fonts-8022a0771c.css"],"current_user_id":"166","current_user_global_id":"10000000000166","current_user_roles":["user","student","admin"],"current_user_is_student":true,"current_user_types":["AccountAdmin"],"current_user_disabled_inbox":false,"current_user_visited_tabs":null,"discussions_reporting":false,"files_domain":"learn.nagaed.com","group_information":null,"DOMAIN_ROOT_ACCOUNT_ID":"10000000000001","k12":true,"help_link_name":"Help","help_link_icon":"help","use_high_contrast":true,"auto_show_cc":true,"disable_celebrations":false,"disable_keyboard_shortcuts":false,"LTI_LAUNCH_FRAME_ALLOWANCES":["geolocation *","microphone *","camera *","midi *","encrypted-media *","autoplay *","clipboard-write *","display-capture *"],"DEEP_LINKING_POST_MESSAGE_ORIGIN":"https://example.com.com","DEEP_LINKING_LOGGING":null,"comment_library_suggestions_enabled":false,"SETTINGS":{"open_registration":false,"collapse_global_nav":true,"release_notes_badge_disabled":false},"FULL_STORY_ENABLED":false,"RAILS_ENVIRONMENT":"production","DIRECT_SHARE_ENABLED":true,"CAN_VIEW_CONTENT_SHARES":true,"FEATURES":{"featured_help_links":false,"lti_platform_storage":false,"scale_equation_images":true,"buttons_and_icons_cropper":true,"calendar_series":false,"account_level_blackout_dates":false,"account_calendar_events":false,"rce_ux_improvements":false,"render_both_to_do_lists":false,"course_paces_redesign":false,"course_paces_for_students":false,"rce_better_paste":false,"module_publish_menu":false,"explicit_latex_typesetting":false,"dev_key_oidc_alert":false,"rce_new_external_tool_dialog_in_canvas":false,"rce_show_studio_media_options":false,"rce_improved_placeholders":false,"product_tours":false,"files_dnd":true,"usage_rights_discussion_topics":false,"granular_permissions_manage_users":false,"create_course_subaccount_picker":true,"lti_deep_linking_module_index_menu_modal":false,"lti_multiple_assignment_deep_linking":false,"buttons_and_icons_root_account":false,"extended_submission_state":false,"scheduled_page_publication":false,"send_usage_metrics":false,"embedded_release_notes":true,"canvas_k6_theme":false,"new_math_equation_handling":true},"current_user":{"id":"166","anonymous_id":"4m","display_name":"Demo Student 01","avatar_image_url":"https://example.com/images/messages/avatar-50.png","html_url":"https://example.c.com/about/166","pronouns":null,"avatar_is_fallback":true},"page_view_update_url":"/page_views/a1522686-2c43-4a96-96d0-b7a016f1435a?page_view_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiYTE1MjI2ODYtMmM0My00YTk2LTk2ZDAtYjdhMDE2ZjE0MzVhIiwidSI6MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAxNjYsImMiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTAzVDA2OjA3OjM2LjY2WiJ9.ssj3NOdUAsr5uNVUKDU_UppTM0mVDHbbjMubJ-CL2yg","context_asset_string":"course_464","ping_url":"https://learn.nagaed.com/api/v1/courses/464/ping","TIMEZONE":"Asia/Kolkata","CONTEXT_TIMEZONE":"Asia/Kolkata","LOCALES":["en-GB","en"],"BIGEASY_LOCALE":"en_GB","FULLCALENDAR_LOCALE":"en-gb","MOMENT_LOCALE":"en-gb","rce_auto_save_max_age_ms":86400000,"K5_USER":false,"K5_HOMEROOM_COURSE":false,"K5_SUBJECT_COURSE":false,"LOCALE_TRANSLATION_FILE":"/dist/javascripts/translations/en-GB-d1abd4d256.json","INCOMPLETE_REGISTRATION":null,"USER_EMAIL":"demostudent01@nagaed.com","badge_counts":{"submissions":0},"NEW_USER_TUTORIALS":{"is_enabled":false},"COURSE":{"id":"464","long_name":"Class 9 Maths Demo Course - SC_DSA001_CL09_MAT_2301","pages_url":"https://example.com/courses/464/pages","is_student":true,"is_instructor":true,"front_page_title":"Home Page","default_view":"wiki"},"WIKI_RIGHTS":{"read":true,"view_unpublished_items":true,"create_page":true,"update_page":true,"delete_page":true,"update":true,"publish_page":true},"PAGE_RIGHTS":{"read":true,"update_content":true,"read_revisions":true,"create":true,"update":true,"delete":true},"DEFAULT_EDITING_ROLES":"teachers","WIKI_PAGES_PATH":"/courses/464/pages","COURSE_HOME":true,"COURSE_TITLE":"Class 9 Maths Demo Course","WIKI_PAGE":{"title":"Home Page","created_at":"2023-05-05T14:04:52+05:30","url":"home-page","editing_roles":"teachers","page_id":"25738","last_edited_by":{"id":"1848","anonymous_id":"1fc","display_name":"Litingse Sangtam","avatar_image_url":"https://example.com/images/messages/avatar-50.png","html_url":"https://example.com/courses/464/users/1848","pronouns":null},"published":true,"hide_from_students":false,"front_page":true,"html_url":"https://learn.nagaed.com/courses/464/pages/home-page","todo_date":null,"publish_at":null,"updated_at":"2023-07-18T11:12:09+05:30","locked_for_user":false,"body":"\u003cp\u003e\u003cimg id=\"4791\" src=\"https://learn.nagaed.com/courses/464/files/58677/preview\" alt=\"Asset 09MAT-1.png\" data-api-endpoint=\"https://example.com/api/v1/courses/464/files/58677\" data-api-returntype=\"File\"\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003ch4\u003e\u003cstrong\u003eWelcome to Class 9\u0026nbsp;\u003ci\u003eMathematics\u003c/i\u003e!\u003c/strong\u003e\u003c/h4\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eI am your teacher \u003ci\u003e\u0026nbsp;Sentizulu Longkumer\u003c/i\u003e.\u0026nbsp; Welcome to your digital course. This digital course is developed to support your in-class learning by making use of various interactive tools. You can take up the practice tests and challenge yourself in quizzes to help you learn and track your progression. Please don't hesitate to reach out to me on my contact details below if you have any questions. Click on the button below to get started.\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cspan\u003eHappy Learning!\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cspan style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"\u003e\u003ca class=\"Button Button--primary\" title=\"Getting Started\" href=\"https://learn.nagaed.com/courses/464/pages/getting-started\" data-api-endpoint=\"https://example.com/api/v1/courses/464/pages/getting-started\" data-api-returntype=\"Page\"\u003eGetting started\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003ctable style=\"border-collapse: collapse; width: 97.9048%;\" border=\"0\"\u003e\n\u003ctbody\u003e\n\u003ctr\u003e\n\u003ctd style=\"width: 33.3004%;\"\u003e\u003cimg id=\"2928\" style=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" src=\"https://example.com/courses/464/files/58680/preview\" alt=\"Modules.jpg\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\" data-api-endpoint=\"https://example.com/api/v1/courses/464/files/58680\" data-api-returntype=\"File\"\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003ctd style=\"width: 33.3004%;\"\u003e\u003cimg id=\"2927\" style=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" src=\"https://example.com/courses/464/files/58679/preview\" alt=\"Assignments.jpg\" width=\"200\" height=\"176\" data-api-endpoint=\"https://example.com/api/v1/courses/464/files/58679\" data-api-returntype=\"File\"\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003ctd style=\"width: 33.3019%;\"\u003e\u003cimg id=\"2926\" style=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" src=\"https://example.com/courses/464/files/58678/preview\" alt=\"Grades.jpg\" width=\"170\" height=\"170\" data-api-endpoint=\"https://example.com/api/v1/courses/464/files/58678\" data-api-returntype=\"File\"\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003c/tr\u003e\n\u003ctr\u003e\n\u003ctd style=\"width: 33.3004%;\"\u003e\n\u003cp style=\"text-align: center;\"\u003e\u003cspan style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"\u003e\u003ca class=\"Button Button--secondary\" title=\"Modules\" href=\"https://example.com/courses/464/modules\" data-api-endpoint=\"https://example.com/api/v1/courses/464/modules\" data-api-returntype=\"[Module]\"\u003eModules\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003ctd style=\"width: 33.3004%;\"\u003e\n\u003cp style=\"text-align: center;\"\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp style=\"text-align: center;\"\u003e\u003cspan style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"\u003e\u003ca class=\"Button Button--secondary\" title=\"Assignments\" href=\"https://example/courses/464/assignments\" data-api-endpoint=\"https://example.com/api/v1/courses/464/assignments\" data-api-returntype=\"[Assignment]\"\u003eAssignments\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003ctd style=\"width: 33.3019%;\"\u003e\n\u003cp style=\"text-align: center;\"\u003e\u003cspan style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"\u003e\u003ca class=\"Button Button--secondary\" title=\"Grades\" href=\"https://example.com/courses/464/grades\" data-api-endpoint=\"$CANVAS_COURSE_REFERENCE$/grades\" data-api-returntype=\"Page\"\u003eGrades\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003c/tr\u003e\n\u00…</script>
```

I tried this method but I lost to get value from 'long_name' and 'ID' from the script

document.getElementsByTagName("script")[6].innerHTML

Comment: The only thing this script does is define 2 variables `INST` and `ENV`. As far as I can see, you can access `long_name` using `ENV.COURSE.long_name`, but please add more details to the question about what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: By `ID` you probably mean `ENV.COURSE.id` - it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the data you want via `ENV.COURSE.long_name` and `ENV.COURSE.id`. If these are undefined, it's most likely due to how your scripts are set up. Ensure that the script defining the variables is executed before the script that uses them, by either placing the init script (the one you pasted) higher in the HTML file or by adding a `defer` attribute to the script tag where you use these variables.

Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts) SO question for more details on how to use the `<script>` tags.