# Order of scripts executions on html page (both sync and unsync)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand the async attribute and its effect on order of executions.

I have an html file including:

1. script A- logs 'A' to the console and dynamically adding an external **async** script.
2. script B- logs 'B' to the console.
3. dynamically added script- logs 'dynamic async script' to the console.

The files are:

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      (function () {
        console.log('A');
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        var t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        e.src = './test.js';
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.async = true;
        t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t);
      })();
    </script>
    <script>
        function wait(ms){
              var start = new Date().getTime();
              var end = start;
              while(end < start + ms) {
                  end = new Date().getTime();
              }
        }
        // wait(120000)
      console.log('B');
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
console.log('dynamic async script');
```

So far, I always see the logs in the following order: 'A', 'B', 'dynamic async script'.

from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp, I understood that async script will download in parallel to page parsing and will execute once available. So, I expected to **sometimes** see the logs in this order: 'A', 'dynamic async script', 'B'. But I couldn't replicate it (tried on safari, chrome and firefox after reading [load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts)), unless I use setTimeout, which I think makes script B async and hence the order is different.

What makes script B always execute before the dynamically added script?
Is there a way to keep script B synchronous and to see they dynamically added script log before?

Thanks

- Note, as seen on code I tried adding a loop for waiting 2 minutes before logging on script B. But I think that since script B is still executed before, it just means that the thread is on this script and will not execute the dynamically added async script.

Comment: All inline scripts are executed synchronously. So script B will be executed synchronously before the async script can run.

Comment: Note that your `wait()` function is not a good way to implement a delay. It runs synchronously and blocks any async activity. Use `setTimeout()` to delay something.

Comment: If script A took two minutes after starting to load the script, the script might be available in time before B. But your B script is inline and available immediately after script A, so of course that's faster than the dynamically loaded script. It doesn't matter if you wait in script B or not, it always runs to completion before another script may execute.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and suggestions!
@Bergi are you suggesting to add a 2 minute wait in script A after adding the dynamic script? If so I tried now, but still wasn't able to make the dynamic script be before B. Is it because as you said the inline script is immediately available when A ends?