# Using CDN clears page content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, knockout.js, cdn

I have a reference to a CDN on my page with a fallback script in case this cannot be reached.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.min.js" integrity="sha384-PA7LgTHoYGwvEy2evWvC3sNOQlmK/vfk//sStiSk3QK3fUDO8oN3VKvHgSPyVKqx" crossorigin="anonymous" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">(window.ko)||document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/knockout?v=20200622" ><\/script>');</script>
```

This reference is placed on html file that is dynamically loaded by ajax and added with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ url: action, cache: false }).done(
   function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { contentCtrl.html(jqXHR.responseText); }
);
```

But when this html is added on the page, the page is cleared, and only the html for the fallback remains. Anyone know how I can solve this? (I suspect this has something with the document.write that is executed from the fallback?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) `document.write` clears the page by calling `document.open` first after the page is loaded (which is your use case since I assume your ajax call happens after loading the page). You might want to look into [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead.

Comment: This looks indeed like it's the problem, but I don't understand why it is executed, since "window.ko" should already be "true" and thus shouldn't execute the fallback...

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94141/javascripts-document-write-inline-script-execution-order/94744#94744)